# Python3 can't repeat the loop after else statement (googled it and did'nt find a solid resault)

Tags: python

can't repeat the loop after the "else statement" (googled it and did'nt find a   solid resault)
example:
I'm trying to make a dice game

```
import random
import time

print("=" * 34)
print("= Welcome to Roll the Dice Game. =")
print("=" * 34)
min = 1
max = 6
user_input = input("Roll the Dice? [Y/N] ")
def dice_roll():
    time.sleep(1)
    print("Rolling dices...")
    time.sleep(1)
    print("Getting the values...")
    time.sleep(1)
    dice1 = random.randint(min, max)
    dice2 = random.randint(min, max)
    print(" Dice #1 -&gt; ", dice1)
    print(" Dice #2 -&gt; ", dice2)
    time.sleep(1)
    dices_sum = dice1 + dice2
    print(" The sum is", dices_sum)

while user_input:
    if user_input == 'Y' or user_input =='y':
        print(dice_roll())
    elif user_input =='N' or user_input == 'n':
        print('exiting')
    else:
        print('Invalid')
    continue    
    user_input = input("Roll again? [Y/N] ")
    print(user_input)
```

Comment: first time here so sorry for the weird text

Comment: The code below the `continue` can not be reached. Remove it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your while loop needs a condition. While x == 1: or while 1:

If you use x = 1. When the value of x is other than 1, the while loop will stop or when a break is used.

If you use while 1, it will continue to loop until you use break.

Another point, you want to have the user_input within the while loop so that it can ask the user if they would like to roll again.

```
import random
import time
print("=" * 34)
print("= Welcome to Roll the Dice Game. =")
print("=" * 34)
min = 1
max = 6

def dice_roll():

    time.sleep(1)
    print("Rolling dices...")
    time.sleep(1)
    print("Getting the values...")
    time.sleep(1)
    dice1 = random.randint(min, max)
    dice2 = random.randint(min, max)
    print(" Dice #1 -&gt; ", dice1)
    print(" Dice #2 -&gt; ", dice2)
    time.sleep(1)
    dices_sum = dice1 + dice2
    print(" The sum is", dices_sum)

x = 1

while x == 1:

    user_input = input("Roll the Dice? [Y/N] ")
    print(user_input)
    if user_input == 'Y' or user_input =='y':
        print(dice_roll())
    elif user_input =='N' or user_input == 'n':
        print('exiting')
        break
    else:
        print('Invalid')
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Answer: As noted by Klaus, removing the `continue` in the while user_input will fix the loop, to only re-roll when the user responds 'y'
2. Changing `print(dice_roll())` to just `dice_roll()` (function call without printing it's return value) will keep this program from printing 'None' after dice rolls.

   - If you want it to print the return, you can change the 
     `print(" The sum is", dices_sum)` to 
     `return(" The sum is", dices_sum)`

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
import random
import time

print("=" * 34)
print("= Welcome to Roll the Dice Game. =")
print("=" * 34)

min = 1
max = 6


def dice_roll():
    time.sleep(1)
    print("Rolling dices...")
    time.sleep(1)
    print("Getting the values...")
    time.sleep(1)
    dice1 = random.randint(min, max)
    dice2 = random.randint(min, max)
    print(" Dice #1 -&gt; ", dice1)
    print(" Dice #2 -&gt; ", dice2)
    time.sleep(1)
    dices_sum = dice1 + dice2
    print(" The sum is", dices_sum)


while 1:
    user_input = input("Roll? [Y/N] ")
    print(user_input)
    if user_input == 'Y' or user_input == 'y':
        dice_roll()
    elif user_input == 'N' or user_input == 'n':
        print('exiting')
        break
    else:
        print('Invalid')
```

There are two problems that you need to fix.

1. Since your function `dice_roll` ends without return syntax, python interpreter will add `return None` at the end of the function. I **change 'print(dice_roll())' to 'dice_roll()'**.
2. In your while loop, `if elif else` syntax has covered all situations, the code will never go to

```
user_input = input("Roll again? [Y/N] ")
print(user_input)
```

So, I just **put these two lines in front of 'if elif else'.** and remove ' again'.

Comment: Please add explanation to your answer.

Comment: OK, it has been added.